# Symfony 4 Issues with vitch

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

i'm trying to display some pictures on my "website"
In order to do so, i'm using Vitch.
I did the upload without issues, images are updating into the right folder, but nothing is display when i'm trying to get imgs from my view.

There is my Yaml config file

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm
mappings:
    property_image:
        uri_prefix: /images/properties
        upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/properties'
        namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
```

And there is my view

```
<div class="card mb-4">
<div class="card-body">
{% if property.filename %}
    <img src="/images/properties/{{ property.filename }}">
{% endif %}
    <h5 class="card-title">
        <a href="{{ path('property.show', {slug: property.slug, id: property.id}) }}">
            {{ property.title }}
        </a>
    </h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ property.surface }} m³ - {{ property.city }} ({{ property.postalCode }})</p>
    <div class="text-primary" style="font-size:2rem; font-weigth:bold;">
       {{ property.FormatedPrice }} €
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a custom naming-strategy ... your images aren't displayed because their paths are incorrect.

`VichUploaderBundle` provides a twig method to correctly resolve the path to the images.

**Example usage:**

```
{# 
  the second parameter is the name of the property 
  with the @UploadableField annotation
#}
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(item, 'imageFile') }}">
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer !

Comment: As you're new to stackoverflow you might want to accept the answer with the "V" on the left to close the question if it helped resolve your issue.